# How to know what topics to study while learning to build website?

Tags: self-learning, programming, web-development

We're having a project work where university won't guide us at all. I've decided to use MERN stack to build a website. But I'm confused on what topics should I learn in html, css, javascript etc.

What topics of javascript would be relevant to web development and in what order should they be learnt? Or do I just learn enough to write hello world and move on directly to building? I tried doing that with django, but it didn't work well for me. I fixed codes using stackoverflow but I was learning really nothing. If I had to create that project from scratch by just using google, I could not be able to reproduce it. That's why I'm trying to be more objective in how I approach this learning.

There are sites that are popular like "The Odin Project" for MERN. But what for other things that aren't having such dedicated websites? How do we figure out what topics should we learn?

For eg: In university courses, we've a syllabus for everything.

https://www.inspirenignite.com/mh/csc303-discrete-structures-syllabus-for-cs-3rd-sem-2017-pattern-mumbai-university/

This is the syllabus of Discrete Mathematics of Mumbai University. It's not like everything in the world about discrete math was taught in this syllabus/contents. But enough was taught so that students could learn other concepts and other courses of Undergraduate that have discrete math as preriquisites. That's exactly what I'm needing.

Not knowing the contents that I should be studying would require me to study this book [https://www.amazon.com/Professional-JavaScript-Developers-Nicholas-Zakas/dp/1118026691](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1118026691) from start to finish which is very tough for anyone to do.

Comment: You should look up "full stack" material. (eg. google gives me full-stack-developer-course-syllabus.pdf https://besanttechnologies.com/docs/full-stack-developer-course-syllabus.pdf)

Comment: "We're having a project work where university won't guide us at all" -- ah, just like the real world. "How do we figure out what topics should we learn?" sort of depends on your goals. HTML, CSS, JS (browser and Node) and Mongo are a lot to cover, so instead of learning everything, maybe start from the goal and work backwards to figure out what subset of these domains you need to get to that goal rather than working forwards and winding up heading down paths that aren't relevant to your goal.

Answer (score 1):

That is a great question that also bothers me sometimes. During my excavation on what to study to become a Blockchain developer I stumbled accros a fresh website that helped me learn all the necessary things to become one. The site is called: https://roadmap.sh/, which is a site of "road maps" to learn about various topics.

Comment: Do you know how to use that site? Its UI is confusing. I don't get the proper syllabus from there.